# Difference between ForWriting and ForAppending VBS

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code which generates an array and writes it to a text file.

When I use ForAppending mode to open the file, it writes it in 60 seconds.

When I use ForWriting mode, it writes very slow.

Can anyone please explain why ForAppending mode is way faster than ForWriting?

Thank you.

```
Dim objFSO, objTextFile
Dim strFile
strFile = "U:\Summers.txt"

Set objFSO =     CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1,     ForWriting = 2

Const ForAppending = 8

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
(strFile, ForAppending, True)


imax = 10000000


a = array()
t0 = timer 'Standard array
Redim a(imax)

For i = 0 To imax

 a(i) = strline

Next

msgbox "Array ready."

for i = 0 to ubound(a)

objTextFile.WriteLine(a(i) & vbCrLf)
next

objTextFile.Close

s = s & "[Array " &     FormatNumber(timer - t0, 3, -1) & "]" & vbCRLF



Set a = Nothing

MsgBox s
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you delete `summers.txt` between tests?

Comment: Yes of course. Every time.

Comment: Just thought I’d check as it wasn’t clear in the question and usually it’s the simple things that catch us out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForWriting overwrites an existing file while ForAppending just adds content to the end. If you delete the file manually before each run, that time difference would be strange. I wonder if the overwriting may happen at every WriteLine call, the documentation isn't very specific here.

However, both have considerable overhead due to the many WriteLine calls. You could concatenate strings in RAM and only do a single Write() to gain performance. Or even use an ADODB.Stream object. That's also more reliable with Unicode files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because ForWriting opens a file and overwrites it's content, while ForAppending just writes to the end of it, without overwriting.

Comment: I see, but the file is created by the script, so there is nothing to overwrite. And the speed difference  is pretty big. Thanks for your answer.